# Carousel in ReactJS using ReactAnimationGroup

Tags: reactjs, carousel

I am trying to create a scrolling carousel, similar to bootstrap's carousel, using pure React and inline styles.

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how state should be.

Here is the relevant code:

Parent component:

`customers.jsx`

```
<button style={{zIndex: 100}} onClick={() => this.renderPrev()}>Prev</button>
<ReactTransitionGroup transitionName="example">
    {_.map(customers, (customer, i) => {
        if (this.state.selected === i){
            return <Customer
                key={customer.name}
                customer={customer}
                selected={this.state.selected}
                idx={i}
                moving={this.state.moving}
                toggle={()=>this.toggle()}
             />
         } else {
             return null
         }
     })
}
</ReactTransitionGroup>
<button style={{zIndex: 100}} onClick={() => this.renderNext()}>Next</button>
```

`renderPrev/renderNext` are simply functions that checks to see if the current selected customer is the first or last one, and if it is, then loop around.

Child component

`customer.jsx`

```
render() {
<div style={_.assign({},styles.root, position)}>
    <div style={{verticalAlign: 'middle'}} >
        <img style={styles.image} className="img-circle img-responsive" width="200px" src={this.props.customer.image}/>
        <img style={styles.logo} className="img-responsive" src={this.props.customer.logo}/>
        <h3 style={{color: '#F05A28', margin: 0,}}>{this.props.customer.name}</h3>
        <h4 style={{fontWeight: 200, margin: 0,}}>{this.props.customer.title}</h4>
        <p style={{fontSize: 16}}>{this.props.customer.description}</p>
    </div>
    <button onClick={()=>this.props.toggle()}>Click</button>
</div>
}
```

I'm able to get carousel to work, but it's static. Ideally, I want the customers to slide left/right depending on if it's going to the next or previous customer.

My attempted solution was to try to send new props into the current customer when the next button is pressed, but the current customer never receives those new props because it's not even rendered due to the conditional.

I think the main problem is that only one customer is rendering at a time due to the condition within the map, and that customer does not get the index of the next customer.

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

I know there's React Slick Carousel but I wasn't able to get it to work, so I wanted to try my hand at doing it myself.

Comment: As you say, drop the conditional. Then alter `this.state.customers` on next/prev.

Comment: So the `customers` array should be set into the state? I have it as a variable in my `render` function.